# how to change mschart label arrow color

Tags: c#, mschart

Simple question. But I can't find an answer yet. How to change label line color in mschart:

[alt text http://img12.imageshack.us/img12/8816/chartjo.png](http://img12.imageshack.us/img12/8816/chartjo.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
        chartArea1.AxisX.MajorTickMark.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        chartArea1.AxisX.MinorTickMark.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
```